# Retrieve data from mysql table using Python CGI Framework

Tags: python, html, mysql, apache2

I am trying to retrieve the data from MySQL database using Python CGI Framework while hosting the program on the web. But unable to get the result, instead of encountering an error while taking the user input.

http://www.extappdynamics.com/cgi-bin/fsearch1.cgi

Can someone please help me in solving this error. Appreciate your help, Thank you.

This is using Python CGI Framework and MySQL database. Trying to host the program on an apache2 server. OS - Linux Ubuntu.

```
fsearch1.py

#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3 as sq
import mysql.connector as mx
import sys
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()


def htmltop():
    print("""Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n
    <!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
    <table border='1'><tr><th>EMPLOYEE NUMBER</th><th>BIRTHDAY</th><th>FIRST NAME</th><th>LAST NAME</th><th>GENDER</th><th>HIRE DATE</th>
    <th>DEPARTMENT NAME</th><th>DEPARTMENT NUMBER</th></tr>""")

def htmltail():
    print("""</body></html>""")

def connectdb():
    mydb=mx.connect(host='localhost',user='******',passwd='*******',database='emp')
    cur=mydb.cursor()
    return mydb,cur

def retrieve(mydb,cur):
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
#       print (form['valuetosearch'])
    if form.getvalue('valuetosearch'):
#               valuetosearch = form.getvalue("valuetosearch")
            query = "SELECT * from emptbl WHERE (empno || bday || fname || lname || gender || hdate || depname || depno LIKE ?)"
            result = cur.execute(query,search).fetchall()
            #form.getvalue['valuetosearch'])
            #result=cur.fetchall()
            print(result)
            print("here")
            return result
            print("connection established")
    else:
            print("Enter to search based on the below table:<br><br>")
    #cur.execute(query)
    #result=cur.fetchall()
    #return result

def displaytest(result):
    print("<table>")
    for x in result:
            print("<tr>")
            print("<td> {0} </td>".format(x[0]))
            print("<td> {0} </td>".format(x[1]))
            print("<td> {0} </td>".format(x[2]))
            print("<td> {0} </td>".format(x[3]))
            print("<td> {0} </td>".format(x[4]))
            print("<td> {0} </td>".format(x[5]))
            print("<td> {0} </td>".format(x[6]))
            print("<td> {0} </td>".format(x[7]))
            print("</tr>")
    print("</table>")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
            htmltop()
            print("<form action = '/cgi-bin/fsearch1.py' method = 'POST'>")
            #print('<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">')
            print('<input type="text" name="valuetosearch" placeholder="Search">')
            print('<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"><br><br>')
            print('</form>')
            mydb,cur=connectdb()
            result=retrieve(mydb,cur)
            displaytest(result)
            cur.close()
            htmltail()
    except:
            cgi.print_exception()
```

I am expecting the results to be something like this which I have in PHP.
http://www.extappdynamics.com/cgi-bin/fsearch1.php

But when I'm trying to compile the program - This is the error that I get

```
<H3>Traceback (most recent call last):</H3>
<PRE>  File "fsearch1.cgi", line 71, in &lt;module&gt;
displaytest(result)
  File "fsearch1.cgi", line 48, in displaytest
for x in result:
<B>TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `form.getvalue('valuetosearch')` is probably evaluating to false. This is not a good modern way to do web development with Python.

Comment: Okay. I figured that out. Is there any other way, any suggestions?